# I need to make an analysis of accumulated value for each day of a time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, time-series

I have a DataFrame that have a time series. I need to get the first line and to add like my investment. The next line is another day and I need compare to get the values differences, which will be my accumulated values for 1 day.

My data:

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOv3g.png)

Translating: 
Data = Date

Cota = Quota

Patrimonio Liquido = net worth

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
len_fundo = len(self.fundo)
    investiment = self.fundo.iloc[0]
    dict_accumulated = {}
    for value in range(1, len_fundo):
        next_line = self.fundo.iloc[value]
        dict_accumulated['Data'] = next_line['Data']
        dict_accumulated['Acumulado'] = next_line['PL'] - investiment['PL']
        investiment = next_line
        accumulated = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_accumulated, index=[value])
    return accumulated
```

But the result is only the last line.

```
  Data         Acumulado
4 2019-12-06   942355.3
```

I know this is because python dict does not accept duplicate keys; therefore, it replaces the keys, but how can I resolve this case?
I need to generate a new DF with Date and Accumulated Values columns for each day...

The result will be a new DF like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr0aC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

```
df['gains'] = df['current'].shift(1) - df['current'] # difference per day
df['acumulado'] = df['gains'].cumsum() # for cumulative sum of gains
```

Using loops with `pandas` is generally poor practice

Comment: Your solution solves my problem partially because I need the date field too.
I provided more information about my problem, changed my post, and added images and examples...

Comment: the date won't be affected. that's just adding new columns

Comment: Ok, but, I don't need to return all fields, only Date and Gains... So, I think to create a new Data Frame that receives Date and Gains, but I can't do that.

Comment: just drop them using `df = df.drop(['col1', 'col2'], axis=1)`, you don't need to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a fully functioning example, so I can't test that this works as intended, but can't you just make `dict_accumulated['Data']` and `dict_accumulated['Acumulado']` lists and then append to them in each loop? Something like this:

```
    len_fundo = len(self.fundo)
    investiment = self.fundo.iloc[0]
    dict_accumulated = {}
    dict_accumulated['Data'] = []
    dict_accumulated['Acumulado'] = []
    for value in range(1, len_fundo):
        next_line = self.fundo.iloc[value]
        dict_accumulated['Data'].append(next_line['Data'])
        dict_accumulated['Acumulado'].append(next_line['PL'] - investiment['PL'])
        investiment = next_line
        accumulated = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_accumulated, index=[value])
    return accumulated
```